# Google Charts: How to increase width of tooltip

Tags: html, css, charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts column charts.
[image]

Here in the if you observe Server Calculation Time value got breaked to next line.
As of requirement it should be in same line.
Please help me possible solutions

Comment: Can you produce it on jsfiddle? So we can work on it.

Answer (score 6):

set chart option `tooltip` to ensure html tooltips are shown

```
  tooltip: {
    isHtml: true
  }
```

then you can override the tooltip class,
use following css to prevent wrapping...

```
.google-visualization-tooltip-item {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found Google chart is manually setting the dimensions of the tooltip directly into the style attribute of the div, ie. as so:

```
<div class="google-visualization-tooltip" style="width: 144px; height: 54px; left: 169.167px; top: 42.5px;">
  // my content
</div>
```

As per the [instructions from Google](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#customizing-html-content) I did set the content as HTML true, but I have had to add the following rules to the `google-visualization-tooltip` class to get around this frustrating size limitation:

```
.google-visualization-tooltip {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: unset !important;
  height: unset !important;
}
```

I can now actually set the content to be my custom requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some CSS properties on this class `.google-visualization-tooltip`:

`.google-visualization-tooltip { width:300px; background-color: red; }`

As shown in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/zrmwtj3z/

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is not to increase the width of the tooltip manually. Instead, in the HTML for your tooltip, wrap the whole thing in a `div` element. Use the CSS style `white-space: nowrap;` to force it to stay on the same line. I also like to add `margin: 1em;` in order to make it look a little bit nicer.